# isPointInPath breaks when canvas re-sizes or scrolled

Tags: canvas, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive canvas but when I re-size the screen in chrome using device tools, it breaks isPointInPath. Even when i don't re-size the canvas and just scroll manually, it still breaks. It can't seem to detect the shape using touch event

```
#canvas{width:100%,
        max-width:1000px}

<canvas id="canvas" width=200 height="200" />

 $canvas
        .on('touchstart mouseup',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let x = e.clientX,
            y = e.clientY,
            mouseX = parseInt(x-offsetX),
            mouseY = parseInt(y-offsetY);

            var i=0;
            for(i=0; i<paths.length; i++){

                insideCL=ctx.isPointInPath(paths[i], mouseX,mouseY);

                if(insideCL){
                    break;
                }
            } 

    for(var i=0; i<colors.length; i++){

        if (colors[i].nameID == "others" || colors[i].nameID == "himself"){
            gradient = Ybigh.colorctx.createLinearGradient(0, colors[i].sx, 0, colors[i].fx);
        }else{
            gradient = Ybigh.colorctx.createLinearGradient(colors[i].sx,0 ,colors[i].fx, 0);
        }

        gradient.addColorStop(1,    colors[i].col1);
        gradient.addColorStop(0,    colors[i].col2);

        var path1 = new Path2D();//I'm adding the shapes to a path

        path1.moveTo(colors[i].x, colors[i].y);
        path1.lineTo(colors[i].xlt, colors[i].ylt);
        path1.lineTo(colors[i].xlt1, colors[i].ylt1);
        path1.lineTo(colors[i].xlt2, colors[i].ylt2);
        path1.closePath();
        path1.getID(colors[i].nameID);

        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#D0D0D0"; 
        ctx.stroke(path1);
        ctx.fill(path1);

        paths.push(path1);//this is that path array
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.font="11px verdana";
        ctx.strokeText(colors[i].label, colors[i].labelX, colors[i].labelY);

   }
```

Comment: What is `paths`? Please provide full code

Answer (score 1):

I just tested and on my scenario, it seems to work fine...

Here is my sample

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>body{margin:0}</style>
<canvas id="can"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    drawDots();
}

function drawDots() {
    var prop = canvas.width / 10
    var scale = 20 * prop / 50
    for (var x = prop; x < canvas.width - prop*1.5; x += prop)
        for (var y = prop; y < canvas.height; y += prop)
            ctx.rect(x, y, scale, scale);
    ctx.stroke();
}

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(e.clientX, e.clientY)) {
        r = 10
        ctx.fillRect(e.clientX - r/2, e.clientY - r/2, r, r );
    }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
resizeCanvas();
</script>
```

Without the full code to reproduce your issue it will be very difficult to troubleshoot your exact problem.

Comment: I have three shapes I'm trying to scale as the canvas scales (shrink/grow proportional to screen size). They're all trapezoids: let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(630, 0, 375, 0);
gradient.addColorStop(1,    "white");
gradient.addColorStop(0,    "#4f87ff");
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(550, 185);
ctx.lineTo(370, 225);
ctx.lineTo(370, 340);
ctx.lineTo(550, 380);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

Comment: @BillPope I made some slight modifications to my sample, now my shapes scale with the canvas ... No errors from isPointInPath